Equivalent to discriminant analysis with categorical variables as predictors
I have a dataset where students vote for a class speaker. This dataset includes the student's id, the class speaker that he/she is voting for, and his/her sociodemographic characteristics (gender, age, country of origin).
I want to know which variables help me discriminate more between students who vote for class speaker A vs other class speakers. In canonical discriminant analysis, this is easy to do with numerical predictor variables. How can I do this with categorical predictor variables?
If I use multiple logistic regression, I can only interpret pairwise comparison...
